# Restaring Azure Web Apps

Tags: azure-powershell

I wanted to restart my app service using Web Jobs. I have written a power shell script.Connection to Azure using service Principle is returning empty subscription Id,subscription Name
Below is my code:

I have tried the below code.When I am connecting manually.The whole process works.But i need to achieve it through service principle

```
$azureAplicationId =""

$azureTenantId= ""
$azurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$psCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($azureAplicationId , $azurePassword)
Add-AzureRmAccount -Credential $psCred -TenantId $azureTenantId  -ServicePrincipal 
Restart-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName "devRG" -Name "draftfoxdatamanagementdev"
```

Error:

```
Account          : Got details
SubscriptionName : 
SubscriptionId   : 
TenantId         : got details
Environment      : got details

Restart-AzureRmWebApp : 'this.Client.SubscriptionId' cannot be null.
At C:\Users\tingu.marina.john\Documents\testingservice.ps1:6 char:1
+ Restart-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName "devRG" -Name "draftfoxdatam ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Restart-AzureRmWebApp], ValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.WebApps.Cmdlets.WebApps.RestartAzureWebAppCmdlet
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script should work, I suppose you have not added your service principal as an [RBAC role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview) in your subscription/web app.

To fix the issue, ask the `Owner` of the subscription navigate to the subscription/web app in the portal > `Access control (IAM)` > Click `Add` > `Add role assignment` > add your service principal as a role(e.g. `Owner`, `Contributor`), see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal) for more details.